# Index page crashes once include statement is added

Tags: php

I am trying to create a site that uses php - with includes.

This page shows up (all php commented out)

```
<?php

//include("header.php");
?>
<div class="row main-row">
<div class="9u">
    <section class="left-content">
            <form method="post" name="update" action="tippytwo2.php" />
            Enter This Week's Numbers: 
            </hr></br></br>
            Num 1   <input type="text" name="ID" />
            </br></br>
            Num 2   <input type="text" name="ID2" />
            </br></br>
            Num 3   <input type="text" name="ID3" />
            </br></br>
            Num 4   <input type="text" name="ID4" />
            </br></br>
            Num 5   <input type="text" name="ID5" />
            </br></br>
            Num 6   <input type="text" name="ID6" />
            </br></br>
               <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" />
            </form>
    </section>

</div>
<!--sidebar starts-->
<?php //include("sidebar.php"); ?>    
<!--sidebar ends-->
</div>
<?php
//include("footer.php");
?>
```

however as soon as I uncomment the include header I get an error saying page is not functioning. Wont even load.

Comment: Have you tried enabling error logging? Check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). The error is most likely within header.php

Comment: You are correct - it is in the header. Dangling paren.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a error in your header file, or it doesn't exist at all.

You should post the PHP error message or the header's code to get more help...

Good luck !

Comment: should be a comment.